# How to set a diapason of possible values or range for css parameter

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Presume, that I have HTML document with next contenet:

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

And I want the background-color to be a random value from a given diapason(aqua, cyan, lime). How should I realize that?

Comment: random value is a job for css custom properties.